# LoadRunner Parameter not saving with value N%2FA

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I was hoping one of you may be able to help answer this scripting problem I am having

In one of my correlations I have a parameter being saved like so…

```
C_RegionValue = “N/A”
```

However when I need replace this value into one of my URL’s the N/A needs to change to N%2FA
So I am accomplishing this by:

```
if ( (strcmp("N/A", lr_eval_string("{C_RegionValue}"))) == 0){
        lr_save_string("N%2FA", "C_RegionValue");
}
```

And this is working properly

```
do_create_RegionString.c(16): Notify: Saving Parameter "C_RegionValue = N/A".
do_create_RegionString.c(18): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "C_RegionValue" =  "N/A"
do_create_RegionString.c(19): Notify: Saving Parameter "C_RegionValue = N%2FA".
```

And I am even able to use that new parameter again in subsequent calls

```
lr_param_sprintf("temp_RString", "&vs_geoType_%d=Region&vs_geo_%d=%s", i, i, 
lr_eval_string("{C_RegionValue}"));

do_create_RegionString.c(23): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "C_RegionValue" =  "N%2FA"
do_create_RegionString.c(23): Notify: Saving Parameter "temp_RString = &vs_geoType_6=Region&vs_geo_6=N%2FA".
```

But for some reason I am not able to use it on this call

```
lr_param_sprintf(lr_eval_string("{RegionString}"), lr_eval_string("{P_RGet_TmpVal}{temp_RString}"));
```

No errors it just never saves the new value, It substitutes everything properly but the value is never saved.
I know this section of the code is working because it does it 5 times prior to this call.

```
do_create_RegionString.c(35): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "RegionString" =  "PickAnyRegion_XL"
do_create_RegionString.c(35): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "P_RGet_TmpVal" =  "&vs_geoType_0=Region&vs_geo_0=Global (All Regions)&vs_geoType_1=Region&vs_geo_1=E&vs_geoType_2=Region&vs_geo_2=GC&vs_geoType_3=Region&vs_geo_3=I&vs_geoType_4=Region&vs_geo_4=NA&vs_geoType_5=Region&vs_geo_5=SA"
do_create_RegionString.c(35): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "temp_RString" =  "&vs_geoType_6=Region&vs_geo_6=N%2FA"
```

And it gets even weirder, If I do not change the value to N%2FA and leave it as N/A, or even if I use the same If statement and change the value to back to N/A everything works properly…

```
do_create_RegionString.c(35): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "RegionString" =  "PickAnyRegion_XL"
do_create_RegionString.c(35): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "P_RGet_TmpVal" =  "&vs_geoType_0=Region&vs_geo_0=Global (All Regions)&vs_geoType_1=Region&vs_geo_1=E&vs_geoType_2=Region&vs_geo_2=GC&vs_geoType_3=Region&vs_geo_3=I&vs_geoType_4=Region&vs_geo_4=NA&vs_geoType_5=Region&vs_geo_5=SA"
do_create_RegionString.c(35): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "temp_RString" =  "&vs_geoType_6=Region&vs_geo_6=N/A"
do_create_RegionString.c(35): Notify: Saving Parameter "PickAnyRegion_XL = &vs_geoType_0=Region&vs_geo_0=Global (All Regions)&vs_geoType_1=Region&vs_geo_1=E&vs_geoType_2=Region&vs_geo_2=GC&vs_geoType_3=Region&vs_geo_3=I&vs_geoType_4=Region&vs_geo_4=NA&vs_geoType_5=Region&vs_geo_5=SA&vs_geoType_6=Region&vs_geo_6=N/A".
```

Any thoughts or idea’s here?

EDIT:

Here is a better example

```
Action()
{

lr_save_string("N/A","C_RegionValue");
lr_save_string("XL_PickAnySearch", "RegionString");
lr_save_string("&vs_geoType_0=Region&vs_geo_0=test","temp_RString");
lr_save_string(lr_eval_string("{temp_RString}"), "XL_PickAnySearch");

/*
Lines 12-13 section will convert N/A into N%2FA, if left uncommented Line 20 
will not save the string, if commented line 20 will save the string
*/
web_convert_param("C_RegionValue", "SourceEncoding=PLAIN", 
"TargetEncoding=URL", LAST);

lr_param_sprintf("temp_RString", "&vs_geoType_%d=Region&vs_geo_%d=%s", 1, 1, 
lr_eval_string("{C_RegionValue}"));

lr_param_sprintf("P_RTmpVal", "{%s}", lr_eval_string("{RegionString}"));
lr_param_sprintf("P_RGet_TmpVal", "%s", lr_eval_string(lr_eval_string("{P_RTmpVal}")));

lr_param_sprintf(lr_eval_string("{RegionString}"), lr_eval_string("{P_RGet_TmpVal}{temp_RString}"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Could you be just missing the %s in the last call?

lr_param_sprintf(lr_eval_string("{RegionString}"),**"%s"**, lr_eval_string("{P_RGet_TmpVal}{temp_RString}"));

I am not sure I understand your problem but I will try and give you couple of directions to go on.

1) `lr_param_sprintf` takes the parameter name as the first argument but it seems you are trying to send it an evaluated parameter in `lr_param_sprintf(lr_eval_string("{RegionString}"), ...`
Maybe you mean `lr_param_sprintf("RegionString",...)`?

2) The change of 'N/A' into 'N%2FA' is known as URL encoding. You can do it without the if with a built in function. See example:

```
lr_save_string("N/A","C_RegionValue");

web_convert_param("C_RegionValue", "SourceEncoding=PLAIN", 
    "TargetEncoding=URL", LAST);


lr_save_string("CA","C_RegionValue");

web_convert_param("C_RegionValue", "SourceEncoding=PLAIN", 
    "TargetEncoding=URL", LAST);
```

Output:

```
Action.c(3): Notify: Saving Parameter "C_RegionValue = N/A".
Action.c(5): web_convert_param started             [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(5): Notify: Saving Parameter "C_RegionValue = N%2FA".
Action.c(5): web_convert_param was successful             [MsgId: MMSG-26392]
Action.c(9): Notify: Saving Parameter "C_RegionValue = CA".
Action.c(10): web_convert_param started          [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(10): Notify: Saving Parameter "C_RegionValue = CA".
Action.c(10): web_convert_param was successful           [MsgId: MMSG-26392]
```

We recommend doing all the manipulations first and making the call to `web_convert_param` only when the final URL is ready.

Hope this helps.

Comment: added better example that you can copy and paste.

Comment: *facepalm*
That was it....
I wonder why it didnt matter if the value wasnt N%2FA. Maybe since there was no placeholder for the special character.. Who knows, thanks for your help!!